# Back button not appearing on UINavigationController

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

**I have a UINavigationController setup in my AppDelegate:**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {          
    // Add the navigation controller's view to the window and display.
    [self.window addSubview:navigationController.view];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

**In my RootViewController I am pushing another view onto the stack:**

```
//Show the deals
    DealViewController *dvc = [[DealViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DealViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:dvc animated:YES];
```

The view shows up, but there is no back button that is added to my navigation bar. Why is this and how can I resolve it?

Comment: How do you allocate the UINavigationController? Look up some sample code and compare it with your implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must think of the navigation controller as a stack of navigation controllers each controlling one screen full of information.
You instantiate the navigation controller with the

```
-(id)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
```

method. You specify the root view controller in this call. Then you add the navigation controller's view as a subview to the window, like you did before.

If you want to show your second screen you push another view controller on the stack by using

```
-(void)pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES
```

method.

Answer (score 24):

Are you setting `self.title` in RootViewController? Perhaps the UINavigationController doesn't have any text to put on the back button, so it omits it...?

Are you setting `hidesBackButton = YES` or `backBarButtonItem = nil` in DealViewController, or does it have a different `leftBarButtonItem` defined?

Comment: Having this issue and have set title and am not hiding the back button. Very weird.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle : @"Back"
                                                         style : UIBarButtonItemStyleDone
                                                        target : nil
                                                        action : nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = back;
[self.navigationController pushViewController : detailViewController animated : YES];
[detailViewController release];
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `presentModalViewController` to show the naviagtionController. Set the navagitionController bar button like so:

```
[navigationController.navigationBar.topItem setLeftBarButtonItem:
    [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Back" 
                                      style: UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                     target: self
                                     action: @selector(dismisstheModal:)] autorelease]];
```

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because in my navigation controller's content controller I had set up some navigation controller behavior in `viewDidLoad` and in another class that inherits from my content controller, and the one that was being presented, i implemented a `viewDidLoad` as well, and forgot to call `[super viewDidLoad]` which thereby caused me to override the base class's `viewDidLoad` where I was setting up my navigation controller buttons.    Oooops.