# Navigation issue with table view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar

i am fresher to IOS development.i want to do something like this.i have a table view with two buttons inside a cell.when i pressed one button it shows a alert view.when i press ok it should show another table view.but in that table view there should be a back button like navigation controller. so far i have done up to alert view. and i tried navigation controller tutorials. but all are done with the table views. i want to do it with alert view action.please someone help me..

and i tried to do this also : add a table view with navigation controller
,add a strong property in appdelegate.h file and in m file i have put below code

```
UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                         bundle: nil];

TableViewController *mainViewController = (TableViewController*)[mainStoryboard
                                                                       instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"requests"];

// UINavigationController *navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
self.navController=[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:mainViewController];
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
[self.window setRootViewController:navController];
[self.window addSubview:navController.view];
[self.window setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

but when i run the app i got this error

2014-03-24 12:18:38.348 varrdle_v2[1378:a0b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'

please some one help me..

thank you

Comment: I think you are getting confused with the alertView.  The alert view isn't used with the navigation controller.  In your alert view delegate `alertView:didDismissWithButtonIndex:` you can push your new tableview onto the navigationcontroller.  If this doesn't help then provide the line of code where you are getting the exception.

Comment: yes i have done it..it goes to my new table view. but there is no back button on the navigation bar. i can not go to my previous view...how can i fix it ?

Comment: Make sure you are setting self.title to something in your root view controller.  If you don't want to have a title in your root view controller then you can add a custom back button - refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060454/back-button-not-appearing-on-uinavigationcontroller

Comment: Back button will not appear because you are not pushing view controller.

Answer (score 1):

You should push the View Controller:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.mainViewController animated:YES];
```

If you set the title of your root view controller to something, your back button will have that inside instead of *Back* (inside `viewDidLoad` method) :

```
self.title = @"Title";
```